# Code meaning and description

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

I have a piece of PHP code I dont understand.

```
private $request;

    public function checkForConfigRequest($observer) {
        $this->request = $observer->getEvent()->getData('front')->getRequest();
        if($this->request->{self::FLAG_SHOW_CONFIG} === 'true'){
            $this->setHeader();
            $this->outputConfig();
        }
    }
```

This is the line I am confused about:

```
if($this->request->{self::FLAG_SHOW_CONFIG} === 'true')
```

I did not use "{" after "->" and what "self::" referring to ?

I appreciate if someone help me understand the syntax so I can write the same code later myself. fell free to point me to external references

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say self::FLAG_SHOW_CONFIG = 'foo'; In this case

`$this->request->{self::FLAG_SHOW_CONFIG}`

means

`$this->request->foo`

More info here http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php.